# Can I reference intermediate nuget package versions without putting them into remote repository?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have 2 solutions in Visual Studio 2012. One solution is a dll project and another one is a desktop app which is using that dll.
I have a NuGet repository set up and all release versions of my dll have been put there. So my desktop app does not reference dll directly - it references a corresponding NuGet package.

I want to modify my dll. My question is as follows. While working on dll modifications I'll have to have some intermediate versions of my dll and I don't want to put them into remote NuGet repository.
Is there a convenient way to make my intermediate dll versions visible for desktop app?

I'm looking for something similar how maven does things in Java world (it looks for a version first in a local repository and then in remote one).

Could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit your nuget.config file to include a local source like so:

```
<packageSources>
   <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
   <add key="MyLocalSource" value="C:\MyLocalSource" />
</packageSources>
<disabledPackageSources />
<activePackageSource>
   <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)"  />
</activePackageSource>
```

Then, every time you update your dll, simply put it into the local source folder, and it will automatically be available to your desktop app.